# ArrayList from a servlet replacing old input values after going back to the start (index.html)

Tags: java, html, servlets, arraylist

I'm sending values from my `index.html` to `ServletOne`. On the specified servlet, the values that I have acquired from the `index.html` are going to be stored through session that I am going to be passing on to `ServletTwo`, in which the values from the session at `ServletOne` are going to be stored using an ArrayList.

So, `ServletTwo` is linked back to `index.html` for another passenger application, and the procedure shall be repeated, the only difference is the first passenger application's values shall be stored in a ArrayList.

My speculation on the problem is it actually instantiates a new ArrayList when I go iterate it back to the `ServletTwo` from `index.html`.

Below are the codes:

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="ServletOne">
            Choose your destination:
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="1"> STOP 1
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="2"> STOP 2
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="3"> STOP 3
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="4"> STOP 4
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="5"> STOP 5
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="6"> STOP 6
            Enter Last Name : <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
            Enter First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enter">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is `ServletOne`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        int fare = 0;
        String lName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String fName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String dest = request.getParameter("destination");

        //acquiring the fare of the current passenger
        if(dest.equals("1")){
            fare = 1;
        }else if(dest.equals("2")){
            fare = 3;
        }else if(dest.equals("3")){
            fare = 5;
        }else if(dest.equals("4")){
            fare = 7;
        }else if(dest.equals("5")){
            fare = 9;
        }else if(dest.equals("6")){
            fare = 11;
        }
        //storing values into session
        session.setAttribute("fName", fName);
        session.setAttribute("lName", lName);
        session.setAttribute("dest", dest);
        session.setAttribute("fare", fare);

        out.print("Name: "+lName+", "+fName+"<br>");
        out.print("Destination: "+dest+"<br>");
        out.print("P"+fare+".00<br>");
        out.print("<a href=ServletTwo>go</a>");    

    }
```

This is `ServletTwo`

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        ArrayList<String> lNames = new ArrayList<String>();


        String lName = (String)session.getAttribute("lName");


        //store an element into arraylist
        lNames.add(lName);

        //print the ArrayList
        out.print(lNames);

        //return to index.html to add a passenger
        out.print("<a href=index.html>Again</a>");   


}
```

I am completely sorry if my terminologies are incorrect, the way I asked the question and anything else. If you have better solution to this problem please do give it as well, the only static thing here is that I have to use an ArrayList and two servlets. I have only coded this with the use of the internet (and some similar things from exercises from our classes, which are just VERY VERY simple programs) and then our prof gave us problems way complex for us to do. And our only source is the internet, nothing from the professor is given.

Comment: You have to store the `lNames` list in the session as well and - of cause - you have to get it from the session before adding a new name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the array list object as static variable at class level.
That is, instead of creating arraylist inside doPost method, declare and create it at servlet class level.
Warning: Declaring instance variable in a servlet leads to many multithreading bugs, but in your case it will fulfill your project need.

Comment: Right, it did work. Thanks! Although it's not the full remedy, it will be enough for my project.

Answer (score 0):

every time when you use the session attribute with the same key it replaces the older value with the new one. I think every time you are getting only the current selected value. ArrayList is only persist until the object destroys.If you want all the selected values to be stored  in the session use a jsonArray as lName

- create jsonArray
- add your lName
- store it in session.setAttribute("lName", jsonArray.toString());
- in servlet2 convert the array again and display it.
- in servlet1 get values from session and add them to same jsonArray and then add to session

Comment: What is a jsonArray?

Comment: Please refer this [tutorial point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)